# Updated to Selenium 2.0rc3, pages don't load/read properly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm at wits' end here, and hoping someone's ran into something similar before.

I've been using Selenium 2.0a2 for a while now to test my web application. Now I've updated to rc3, and several tests break when I run them on my teamcity installation.

These tests complain about not finding elements in certain (jsp) pages, so I had the tests log the page source.

In certain tests the pages look like this to the webDriver (as retreived with `webDriver.getPageSource()`):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> *page title* </title>
    *CSS and style code*
  </head>
</html>
```

In other words, all javascript and body information is not loaded/read by the webdriver. This only occurs in certain tests, with others the exact same methods work fine. I've tried several ideas such as reloading the page prior to accessing the element, turning off JSP preloading etc, but nothing has worked so far.

Has anyone run into something like this before? If so, did you solve it and how?

Comment: So it is not loading pages properly even if you just do .get() ? The API changed a fair amount from a2 to rc3 and certain classes got deprecated, etc.

Comment: Are you able to find those elements on page manually? You may like to use Find feature of Selenium IDE to do that

Comment: Well, we don't use Selenium IDE. We just run automated tests. Like I said, this only happens to certain tests, not certain pages. It's all very strange.

Comment: Mike, I've removed all references to deprecated classes already. What I need is somewhere to start looking, really. If there's any particular bit of code you think might be a cause, do tell and I'll bring it out.

Answer (score 0):

The latest released version of Selenium is 2.17.0. Why are you asking questions about a pre-release version nearly one year after its release?? Those numbers mean something, upgrade!!

Comment: Y'know, the question was asked in good ol' june of 2011. Looks like mr Gilbert saw fit to edit it =)